# How can I change line spacing in Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I would like to use the macOS mail app to compose mails with non-standard line spacing.

Are there solutions without using 3rd party software?

Comment: It may be well-known to you but not others & the suggestions you have tried equally unknown. As we cannot see what you already tried, perhaps you could tell us & maybe also link to other places this question has been asked, with non-working answers.

Comment: Not possible in Mail, try Outlook instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple's html editor doesn't engage in that level of formatting. It's still a throw back when mail was plain text and designed to let the receiver decide how to render line breaks and spacing as opposed to being a word processor.

- Some love this since it's optimized for simplicity, speed and clarity.
- Others despise it and want a heavy editing / formatting quiver at their disposal. (or at least heavier in function than was shipped)

You'd need a third party editor (or other app) to pre-author things and compose the mails or choose another client that suits your requirement to get line spacing rich text / html.

Comment: TL;DR - Mail never wanted to be Outlook and Outlook never wanted to be Mail

Comment: I like the simplicity, no questions there. However, the lining adjustment would make any longer text more legible.

Comment: @JoshE. I hear you - when you can’t influence line spacing, your only recourse is to manually add line breaks, lose the flow for variable reading pane widths and make it ugly. Hopefully the people reading your mail know they can increase the default font so they can read what you wrote.